# Prevent User From Entering Characters in a Text Field ,Allow Swiping with Magnetic Stripe Readers (MSR) only

Tags: java, swing

Prevent User From Entering Characters in a Text Field ,Allow Swiping with Magnetic Stripe Readers (MSR) only

The  MSR acts as much as like a keyboard,  instead of  typing manually  from keyboard  the MSR is typing in the text field .
So the challenge is  how to differentiate the MSR and Keyboard.

How can I crack that in java SWING.
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2):

You could start by reading the JavaDocs for [`JTextField`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextField.html) and maybe having a look at [How to Use Text Fields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textfield.html)

The first thing that jumps out at me is [`JTextField#setEditable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#setEditable-boolean-)

Answer (score 2):

In order to prevent users from inserting text in your text field, just use

```
yourTextField.setEditable(false);
```

When reading data from a magnetic stripe reader you would want to populate the text field using:

```
yourTextField.setText(textFromReader);
```

Comment: I am referring same text field for both keyboard event and   magnetic stripe reader. If I do setEditable(false) I cant read data from MSR reader